# How to factor the expression $1+s-t-st$

Tags: factoring

How should this expression be factored $1+s-t-st$ ? I don't know how to begin & I'm clueless.

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First try a partial factorization and see.

Answer (score 2):

When $s=-1$, $1+s-t-st=0$ and similarly for $t=1$. So we have either $(1+s)(1-t)$ or $(1+s)(t-1)$. By inspection, $1+s-t-st=(1+s)(1-t)$

Answer (score 1):

$$1+s-(t+st)$$
$$(1+s)-t(1+s)=(1+s)(1-t)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$1+s-t-st$$

$$=1(1+s)-t(1+s)$$

$$=(1+s)(1-t)$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
1+s-t-st &= 1-t+s(1-t) \\
         &=(1-t)(1+s)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$1+s-t-st$ is same as writing $1\times(1+s)-t(1+s)$.

Now take out $(1+s)$ common you are left with

$(1+s)(1-t)$